I want to use my youtubeplayer in full screen mode, but the screen rotates without taking up all the space
I'm trying to put my YoutubePlayer in full screen mode. Unfortunately, when I press on the full screen world, it turns into landscape mode but doesn't take up the whole screen.
Widget _buildRegularCard() {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.white,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection(widget.collectionName)
                .doc(widget.documentId)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text('Something went wrong');
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            strokeWidth: 15,
                            semanticsLabel: "Chargement",
                        )
                    );
                }

            String? videoId = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(snapshot.data?["video"]);
            YoutubePlayerController controller = YoutubePlayerController(
                initialVideoId: videoId!,
                flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
                    autoPlay: false, 
                    mute: false, 
                    showLiveFullscreenButton: true
                ),
            );

            controller.addListener(() {
                if (controller.value.isFullScreen) {
                    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
                } else {
                    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
                }
            });

            return SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                        Stack(
                            children: [
                                CachedNetworkImage(
                                    height: 400,
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    imageUrl: snapshot.data?["image"],
                                ),
                                LikeButton(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    isLiked: isInFavorites,
                                    size: 60,
                                    onTap: (isLiked) async {
                                        String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? "";

                                        if (uid.isNotEmpty) {
                                            if (isInFavorites == true) {
                                                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                    .collection('Utilisateurs')
                                                    .doc(uid)
                                                    .collection('favoris')
                                                    .doc(widget.documentId)
                                                    .delete();
                                                print("******* Suppresion du jeux");
                                            } else {
                                                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                    .collection('Utilisateurs')
                                                    .doc(uid)
                                                    .collection('favoris')
                                                    .doc(widget.documentId)
                                                    .set({
                                                        'nom': snapshot.data?["nom"],
                                                        'image': snapshot.data?['image'],
                                                        'age': snapshot.data?['age'],
                                                        'but': snapshot.data?['but'],
                                                        'materiel': snapshot.data?['materiel'],
                                                        'nombreJoueurs': snapshot.data?['nombreJoueurs'],
                                                        'rating': snapshot.data?['rating'],
                                                        'type de jeux': snapshot.data?['type de jeux'],
                                                        'video': snapshot.data?['video'],
                                                    });
                                                print("Ajout du jeux");
                                            }

                                            setState(() {
                                                if (isInFavorites == true) {
                                                    isInFavorites = false;
                                                } else {
                                                    isInFavorites = true;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    },
                                    bubblesColor: BubblesColor(
                                        dotPrimaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                        dotSecondaryColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
                                    ),
                                    circleColor: const CircleColor(
                                        start: Colors.yellow, 
                                        end: Colors.green
                                    ),
                                    likeBuilder: (test) {
                                        isInFavorites = test;
                                        test == false
                                            ? Image.asset("assets/icons/unlike.png")
                                            : Image.asset("assets/icons/like.png");
                                    },
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        RatingStarFix(
                            size: 40,
                            collectionName: widget.collectionName,
                            documentId: widget.documentId,
                        ),
                        TextActivitesDescriptionTitle(
                            text: snapshot.data?["nom"],
                            color: const Color(0xffe2324e),
                            size: 50,
                        ),
                        CardActivitiesDescription(
                            text: snapshot.data?["nom"],
                            padding: 0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            subtext: "Nom : ",
                        ),
                        CardActivitiesDescription(
                            text: "age",
                            padding: 0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            subtext: 'Age : ',
                        ),
                        CardActivitiesDescription(
                            text: snapshot.data?["but"],
                            padding: 0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            subtext: "But : ",
                        ),
                        CardActivitiesDescription(
                            text: snapshot.data?["materiel"],
                            padding: 0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            subtext: "Materiel : ",
                        ),
                        CardActivitiesDescription(
                            text: snapshot.data?["nombreJoueurs"],
                            padding: 0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            subtext: 'Nombres Joueurs : ',
                        ),
                        CardActivitiesDescription(
                            text: snapshot.data?["deroulement"],
                            padding: 0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            subtext: 'Deroullement : ',
                        ),
                        snapshot.data?["video"] == ""
                            ? Container(
                                height: 200,
                                width: 200,
                                child: const Center(
                                    child: Text("Video En cour de fabrication "),
                                ),
                            )
                            : Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                child: YoutubePlayerBuilder(
                                    player: YoutubePlayer(
                                        controller: controller,
                                        aspectRatio: 16 / 7,
                                        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                                        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
                                        progressColors: const ProgressBarColors(
                                            playedColor: Colors.amber,
                                            handleColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                                        ),
                                        onReady: () {
                                            controller.addListener(() {});
                                        },
                                    ),
                                    builder: (BuildContext, player) {
                                        return Column(
                                            children: [
                                                player,
                                            ],
                                        );
                                    },
                                ),
                            ),
                        const Divider(height: 40, thickness: 2),
                        const Text(
                            "Commentaires",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        StreamBuilder(
                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection(widget.collectionName)
                                .doc(widget.documentId)
                                .collection('comments')
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                }

                                var comments = snapshot.data!.docs;
                                return ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    itemCount: comments.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        var comment = comments[index];
                                        return ListTile(
                                            title: Text(comment['username']),
                                            subtitle: Text(comment['content']),
                                            trailing: RatingStarDisplay(
                                                size: 20,
                                                rating: comment['rating'],
                                            ),
                                        );
                                    },
                                );
                            },
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => AddCommentPage(
                                            documentId: widget.documentId,
                                            collectionName: widget.collectionName,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                );
                            },
                            child: const Text("Ajouter un commentaire"),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            );
        },
    ),
);
}

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcQhg8aijTdcB3D1OFeV6VBhrMiT8qqG/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yYzgs1NDyZzPxuHQPAu29Mu3aoSNs6IN/view?usp=drive_link
Here's the console error Failed to change device orientation: Error Domain=UISceneErrorDomain Code=101 “None of the requested orientations are supported by the view controller. Requested: portrait; Supported: landscapeLeft, landscapeRight “ UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=None of the requested orientations are supported by the view controller. Requested: portrait; Supported: landscapeLeft, landscapeRight}

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

can you add a screenshot or something?

I've modified the code for the screenshots and errors
Thank you for your response here are the screenshots the first in normal the second when I press the mode full screen more I add the error in copy paste
Regarding the structure of my code I put everything because I did not know if putting only the youtubePlayer it was enough if so do I have to change the body of the question?
